# return statement does not ending method java

Tags: java

```
public class Interpolation_search {

    public static void main(String...s) {
        int rr[]= {1,2,3,4,9,10,15,80};
        System.out.println(search(rr,0,7,3));
    }

    static int search(int ar[], int lo, int hi,int X) {

        if(lo<hi&&ar[lo]!=ar[hi]) {
            int mid=lo + ((hi-lo)/(ar[hi]-ar[lo]))*(X-ar[lo]);
            if(X==ar[mid])
                return 1;      //l1
            else if(X>ar[mid])
                search(ar,mid+1,hi,X);
            else search(ar,lo,mid-1,X);
        }
        return 0;              //l2
    }
}
```

return is executing twice first at l1 and second at l2.

Comment: You recursively call the `search()` method, so it is executed multiple times. Use a step-by-step debugger to visualize the flow if you need. Also note that you should probably return the result of these recursive calls, or do something with them whatsoever.

Comment: If you _call_ it multiple times (which you do), it will _return_ multiple times.

Comment: Unrelated: please avoid proper names. Variable should not be abbreviations, they always go lowerCase. And they should mean something. So `valueToFind` instead of `X`, and `values` instead of `ar`, and ´testValues` instead of `rr`.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have difficulties understanding recursion.

Your method `search()` is supposed to return an int result. And the method itself calls **itself** (using different arguments) repeatedly. Thing is: you are all *ignoring* these recursive calls.

In other words: the real answer is for you to step back and understand what *recursion* is **meant** to be, and how to properly use it. As a starter, you could try to change

```
search(ar,mid+1,hi,X);
```

to

```
return search(ar,mid+1,hi,X);
```